# OpenFileDialog not showing in Visual Studio 2017 (FolderBrowserDialog isn't either!)

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

While coding, I'm getting an open file dialog to tell where a file is for an exe, but when I put it on the design file, it just never shows up. I tried doing it again and running debug. It just never shows up. Not even in release.

Comment: did you tell it to, with code?  Just dragging it to the form doesn't automatically open it.

Comment: Could you give some code?

Comment: ? k ... Can you post your code? ** if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //
            }
**

Comment: I just added the Dialog. I didn't code any yet. I am very inexperienced and new to Visual C#

Comment: What's the code I need to add

Comment: I gave to you code, but you need use it in some method or MainWindow();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                //your code
            }
```